# Rails nested relationships in ActiveRecord

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I would like to query for the sections that belong to schools with these models:

```
School
  has_many :terms

Term
  belongs_to :school
  has_many :departments

Department
  belongs_to :term
  has_many :courses

Courses
  belongs_to :department
  has_many :sections

Section
  belongs_to :course
```

I am a little bit lost as to how to do this.

I would like to be able to call a list of sections that belong to the school and find the school from the sections (and query for all the relationships in between)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In have to iterate through each model from top to bottom.
For example:

```
s = School.find(1)
s.terms.find(1).departments.find(1).courses.find(1).sections
```

This will give you the sections that are associated with `school_id = 1`

Since your model has cascading has many, you have to go like this unless you want to change your database schema..

Answer (score 1):

If you are working with Rails 3.1 or above you can use :has_many :through to help you get the sections that are within each school.  First, you need to set up your relations in your models:

```
School
  has_many :terms
  has_many :departments, :through => :terms

Term
  belongs_to :school
  has_many :departments

Department
  belongs_to :term
  has_many :courses
  has_many :sections, :through => :courses

Courses
  belongs_to :department
  has_many :sections

Section
  belongs_to :course
```

Then to get the sections for a school you can do...

```
School.first.departments.collect{|d| d.sections}.flatten!
```

To get the school that a section belongs to all you need to do is

`section.course.department.term.school`

Answer (score 0):

To find the school from a section, you would just do:

```
section.course.department.term.school
```

If there aren't so many records as to slow this down, you can get an array of sections for a given school by doing:

```
sections = []
school.terms.each do |term|
   term.departments.each do |department|
      department.courses.each do |course|
         course.sections.each do |section|
            sections << section
         end
      end
   end
end
```

That will also give you access to each relationship in-between if you need to do any further processing.

And here's a terser version:

```
sections = school.terms.map(&:departments).flatten.map(&:courses).flatten.map(&:sections).flatten
```